# Converting a pointer back to an array in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a function `*getText()` where the end result is an array which I need to return from the function. As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible directly, so I created a pointer as follows:

```
char *ptr = &plainText[0];
return ptr;
```

I'm still fairly new to C and am not entirely comfortable working with pointers, so I created a little bit of code to convert the pointer back to an array in the function I need it in:

```
int i;
char plainText[256];
for (i=0; *(getText()+i) == '\0'; i++){
    plainText[i] = *(getText()+i);
}
```

The idea here is that the for loop will go through the string the pointer points to until it finds the end (`'\0'`) and for every character, append the string.

However, although the program compiles in gcc with no compiler errors, it aborts without any runtime errors when it gets to this segment of code.

Could anyone give me some guidance on getting this to work?

James

Comment: Are you returning the address of a local variable?

Comment: Get comfortable working with pointers!

Comment: You don't need help getting that to work. You need to go back and rethink what you are doing.

Comment: what are you trying to do? :)    and can you paste more of the code? global variable, gettext

Comment: In C the only useful thing an array does for you is reserve space. After you have reserved the space it makes no difference if you use an array name or a pointer. (Almost no difference: sizeof returns different values. It is very bad practice to rely on sizeof for array length, declare a size_t array_len to use instead because when the code changes to use a pointer there are no sudden surprises.)

Comment: @Zan: Hmmm...arrays do one other thing: they know how long the fast indexing dimensions of multidimensional arrays are.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it carefully, you'll see that "converting a pointer to an array" **makes no sense**.

An array is a *contiguous block of memory* to which *you gave a name*.

A pointer is a memory *address*.

You can't convert a pointer to an array -- how would you suddenly change an address back to a block of memory? You would need to instead create a new block, and copy whatever you want to there instead.

Provided, of course, that the original pointee *exists* in the first place. In your case, it seems like it's a local array, which means that it is destroyed by the time you try to copy its data to another array.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant `*(getText()+i) != '\0'`, otherwise your loop condition will always terminate immediately

Comment: Yes I did mean that! I've made that change but the program still aborts when it gets to that bit of code.

Comment: Use your debugger to find out your bug. Learning to use a debugger effectively is essential when learning programming in C.

Answer (score 1):

This is amazing.  Just don't do anything that you are doing, step back, take a deep breath....

C functions that need to return an array usually do so by simply taking a pointer and a max size as arguments, and writing into that space.  See [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/) for example.

All this copying back and forth should be a red flag that something wasn't right.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Read a good C programming book. You'll learn that *arrays are very often* (but **not always**) *considered as pointers*.

You probably don't want to call `getText()` at every iteration, so put it into a variable.

Your test should be "*different of the null character*".

Compile with all warnings enabled and for debugging. With `gcc` on Linux that means `gcc -Wall -g`. Learn how to use a debugger like `gdb` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to array is same as pointer to first element in an array. It's just an address value.

So

char ch[10];

ch is same as &ch[0]

Now you don't need any of this to copy a null terminated string. Just use strcpy()

Comment: What you said is not technically correct. `ch` is **not** the same as `&ch[10]`, because `sizeof(ch) != sizeof(&ch[0])`. It is more correct to say that in *certain contexts*, `ch` will reduce to a pointer that points to the first element in the array.

Comment: @dream lax. Yep you're right. I meant they point to same address in memory.