# Do I need to dynamically allocate double arrays to pass them?

Tags: c++

Here's a simple compile error, I'm allocating double arrays like so:

```
double mixmu[][1]  = {{1},{-1}};
double mixvar[][1] = {{1},{1}};
double coef[]      = {1,1};
```

can I not pass these as double** objects?

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MixtureModel::MixtureModel(int, int, double [2], double [2][1], double [2][1], Distribution*)’
./problems/MixtureModel.h:25: note: candidates are: MixtureModel::MixtureModel(int, int, double*, double**, double**, Distribution*)
```

Comment: You'll have a much better time with vectors, but do yourself a favour and read up on how this works too.

Comment: An array is not a pointer.  *An array is not a pointer*.  **An array is NOT a pointer**.

Comment: You can use an explicit cast to double**, but I am not sure whether this is a good idea.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield [But I heard that char `a[]` was identical to `char *a`](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Comment: For sake of reference/clarity the question should be updated with *how* the variables are used in said invocation.

Comment: Try reading [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8514058/541686)?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yep, that answer makes it obvious, thanks for the comments everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between types int** and int\[\]\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395255/what-is-difference-between-types-int-and-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Do I need to dynamically allocate double arrays to pass them?**

No you don't!
Your misconception/doubt stems from the (Incorrect)fact that, Arrays are pointers

***No! Arrays are not pointers!!***
An array name decays sometime to an pointer to its first element in scenarios where array name is not valid.

A two dimensional array does not decay to an double pointer. It decays to an pointer to array.

Your declaration needs to be:

```
MixtureModel::MixtureModel(int, int, double [2], double [2][1], double [2][1], Distribution*);
```

or

```
MixtureModel::MixtureModel(int, int, double *, double(*)[1], double (*)[1], Distribution*);
```

---

**Good Read:**
[How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)